# Combine 2 tables into 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

How would I combine 2 tables into 1? Maybe using INNER JOIN? Please advise. Thank you.

For example, with the following db I just created:

Table 1

```
  +----------------------+
  | Places               |
  +----------------------+
  | Cupertino            |
  | BJ's Restaurant      |
  | Cupertino Inn        |
  | Outback Steakhouse   |
  +----------------------+
```

Table 2

```
  +----------------------+
  | Distant              |
  +----------------------+
  | 0.6 km               |
  | 1.3 km               |
  | 1.3 km               |
  | 1.1 km               |
  +----------------------+
```

Select syntax and combine this table output would be something like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| Places              | Distant |
+---------------------+---------+
| Cupertino           | 0.6 km  |
| BJ's Restaurant     | 1.3 km  |
| Cupertino Inn       | 1.3 km  |
| Outback Steakhouse  | 1.1 km  |
+---------------------+---------+
```

**Edit: Sorry forgot to add id. Updated below:

Table 1

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|Places_Id  | Places             |
+-----------+--------------------+
| 1         | Cupertino          |
| 2         | BJs Restaurant     |
| 3         | Cupertino Inn      |
| 4         | Outback Steakhouse |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

Table 2

```
+------------+----------+
|Distant_Id  | Distant  |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | 0.6 km   |
| 2          | 1.3 km   |
| 3          | 1.3 km   |
| 4          | 1.1 km   |
+------------+----------+
```

Places_Id and Distant_Id is `Auto Increment`. So sorry guys, suddenly my brain stop working after long time not doing programming related. Turns out this is so easy after add the id into database. Thanks guys for all the answers. Keep it up.

```
Select A.Places, A.Places_Id, B.Distant, B.Distant_Id from Table1 A, Table2 B where B.Distant_Id = A.Places_Id
```

Comment: without foreign keys it´s not possible

Comment: This design is BAD , you should always add foreign key that relates between two relational tables. add column ID to table 1, and place_id to table 2

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no way to (correctly) combine these tables, because there is no correspondence between the values.

Comment: Are you showing us all columns of the two tables? By what rule do you combine the records? Why do you combine 'Cupertino' with '0.6 km' and not, say, '1.1 k`m' for instance?

Comment: Because this value from google distance matrix api (distance) and places api (places). Which means the result is distance output from current location to destination locations. Current location is Apple One Infinite Loop. That's why you see Cupertino with 0.6km duration from Apple One Infinite Loop.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have no way to "correspond" the values in the two tables, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you are loading the data into the tables from an external source, then include an `auto_increment` column to get the original ordering.

Lacking that, you can get something like what you want, by enumerating the rows in each table and joining/aggregating on that.  This comes close to what you want:

```
select max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2
from ((select t1.col as col1, NULL as col2, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as seqnum
       from table1 t1 cross join (select @rn1 := 0) params
      ) union all
      (select NULL, t2.col, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum
       from table2 t2 cross join (select @rn2 := 0) params
      )
     ) tt
group by seqnum;
```

This does not guarantee the original ordering in the tables, but it will produce a new table combining exactly one row from each of the other two tables.

Answer (score 1):

in table2 you need to have a column to identify which entry of table1 belongs to the entry in table2, so a foreign key is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some id's then you can do a join:

```
SELECT A.field, A.otherfield, B.field, B.otherfield, C.yetanotherfield
FROM table_A AS A
JOIN table_B as B on A.id = B.a_id
JOIN table_C as C on B.id = C.b_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution by using user variables.

SQL:

```
-- Prepare data, just for demo
create table table1(Places varchar(200));
create table table2(Distant varchar(200));

insert into table1 values
('Cupertino'),
("BJ's Restaurant"),
('Cupertino Inn'),
('Outback Steakhouse');
insert into table2 values
('0.6 km'),
('1.3 km'),
('1.3 km'),
('1.1 km');
select * from table1;
select * from table2;

-- Process of combination
SET @rownum1:=0; 
SET @rownum2:=0; 
SELECT t1.Places, t2.Distant
FROM 
    (SELECT *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum FROM table1) t1, 
    (SELECT *, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum FROM table2) t2
WHERE t1.rownum = t2.rownum ;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+--------------------+
| Places             |
+--------------------+
| Cupertino          |
| BJ's Restaurant    |
| Cupertino Inn      |
| Outback Steakhouse |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+---------+
| Distant |
+---------+
| 0.6 km  |
| 1.3 km  |
| 1.3 km  |
| 1.1 km  |
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Process of reporting
mysql> SET @rownum1:=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @rownum2:=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.Places, t2.Distant
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum FROM table1) t1,
    ->     (SELECT *, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum FROM table2) t2
    -> WHERE t1.rownum = t2.rownum ;
+--------------------+---------+
| Places             | Distant |
+--------------------+---------+
| Cupertino          | 0.6 km  |
| BJ's Restaurant    | 1.3 km  |
| Cupertino Inn      | 1.3 km  |
| Outback Steakhouse | 1.1 km  |
+--------------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```